# Bircas HaMazon when starting to eat on Hoshanah Rabbah and finishing on Shmini Etzeres

Tags: sukkot, bentching, meal-seudah, shmini-atzeres

A person eating a seudah on Hoshanah Rabbah wanted to continue eating his seudah when Shmini Etzeres already started. He was "pores mappah", made kiddush and continued to eat. Now, after a meal eaten wholly on Hoshanah Rabbah, one says "Sukkos" in Yaleh V'Yavo in Bircas HaMazon; after a meal eaten wholly on Shmini Etzeres, one says "Shmini Etzeres". So what about this felow who started on Hoshanah Rabbah and ended on Shmini Etzeres: When he recites Bircas HaMazon what day should be mentioned in Yaleh V'Yavo, "Sukkos" or "Shmini Etzeres"? What's the reason why and please cite all sources.

Comment: Your question would be more comprehensible if it'd explain "'pores mappah'".

Comment: What's the difference between this and any other bentching across time boundaries? (e.g., yontiv/not, shabbas/not, chanukah/not, purim/not, etc.)

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Because there are two _contradicting_ things to be said. I'd ask: What's the difference between this and other boundary switches (e.g., yontiv/shabbat, shabbat/rosh chodesh, shabbat/channuka, shabbat/purim, pruim/shabbat, etc.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Maybe a distinction is also warranted between entering vs. exiting k'dushas hayom. For example, for Shabbos --> Rosh Chodesh we recite only r'tzei if the meal began before sh'kiya. On the other hand, going in the other direction and explicitly making kiddush may trump the "beginning of the meal" rule...

Comment: @Fred Not all agree about what to do for Shabbos going into Rosh Chodesh.

Comment: @DoubleAA ... For example, according to Rashi (P'sachim 105a, s.v. שבת היא קבעתה), Shabbos turns the continuation of the meal into a new meal. Whether Yom Tov has this effect is questionable (see Dibros Moshe ad loc., which discusses whether there is an issur t'ima on Yom Tov l'fi the Rashbam; I also heard from R' Gedalia Hochberg that the Sha'ar HaMelech discusses this).

Comment: @DoubleAA "Not all agree about what to do for Shabbos going into Rosh Chodesh." I know, I'm just giving examples. This is a complex topic.

Comment: This question is unique in that it's not a shaila of ratzah together with yaleh v'yavo and ratzah and al hanissim. It's only yaleh v'yavo however which day do we say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pri Megadim in Ashel Avraham Siman 188 Sif-Katan 18 discusses this exact shailo. He writes that it is similar to the shailo of when Rosh Chodesh comes out after Shabbos and one eats after nightfall. According to the Taz one mentions both Shabbos and Rosh Chodesh. He said so to in this case one would mention both Sukkos and Shmini Atzeres (which is quite surprising since it's not 2 seperate things.) However (if I understand correctly) he says that according to the Magen Avraham one "wouldn't say". What I believe he means is that one wouldn't say Sukkos and would only say Shmini Atzeres that is because in the case of Rosh Chodesh coming out Motzei Shabbos the M"A holds that if one eats when it's already night they *only* mention Rosh Chodesh and not Shabbos.

Comment: Maybe you'd say Shmini Atzeret because Sukkot is only for Chol Hamoed so you don't have to repeat if you skip it